# inflating class org.osmdroid.views.MapView cause crash

Tags: android, eclipse, android-mapview, osmdroid

I use eclipse as IDE to write a simple test program that put some TextView and Button on the screen and works fine.

Then, I do...

(1) set compiler compliance level to 15
(2) set ANDROID_SDK_PLATFORM to C:/ADT/sdk/platforms/android-15
(3)add these as external JARs

```
osmdroid-android-4.2.jar
slf4j-android-1.7.7.jar
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission     
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category 
android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/bt_test"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        // return rootView;

        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

compilation ok, apk installation ok, but app crash...
(I use a real phone with android 4.2.2 as debug device.)
Here comes the log:

```
06-06 23:03:06.007: D/jdwp(18476): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3B
06-06 23:03:06.013: D/dalvikvm(18476): open_cached_dex_file :     
/data/app/com.example.test-1.apk /data/dalvik-
cache/data@app@com.example.test-1.apk@classes.dex
06-06 23:03:06.027: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.029: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.032: W/IconCustomizer(18476): can't load     
transform_config.xml
06-06 23:03:06.035: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.040: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.043: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.058: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.060: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.066: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.067: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.069: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.071: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.072: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:06.077: V/Provider/Settings(18476): invalidate     
[secure]: current 7 != cached 0
06-06 23:03:06.080: V/Provider/Settings(18476): from db cache, name 
= access_control_lock_enabled , value = null
06-06 23:03:06.111: D/libEGL(18476): loaded 
/vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
06-06 23:03:06.114: D/libEGL(18476): loaded 
/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
06-06 23:03:06.117: D/libEGL(18476): loaded 
/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
06-06 23:03:06.252: D/OpenGLRenderer(18476): Enabling debug mode 0
06-06 23:03:06.253: V/InputMethodManager(18476): onWindowFocus: 
null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#9810100
06-06 23:03:06.254: V/InputMethodManager(18476): START INPUT: 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4221c418 
V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-720,1280} ic=null 
tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@42289610 controlFlags=#104
06-06 23:03:06.256: V/InputMethodManager(18476): Starting input: 
Bind result=InputBindResult{null 
com.cootek.smartinputv5/.TouchPalIME #4739}
06-06 23:03:06.265: D/skia(18476): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:08.041: I/SurfaceTextureClient(18476): 
[STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5c2c73f8) fps:0.57, dur:1745.04, 
max:1745.04, min:1745.04
06-06 23:03:08.627: D/OpenGLRenderer(18476): Flushing caches (mode     
0)
06-06 23:03:08.845: D/OpenGLRenderer(18476): Flushing caches (mode 
1)
06-06 23:03:08.849: D/OpenGLRenderer(18476): Flushing caches (mode 
0)
06-06 23:03:45.893: D/jdwp(18569): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3B
06-06 23:03:45.899: D/dalvikvm(18569): open_cached_dex_file : 
/data/app/com.example.test-2.apk /data/dalvik-
cache/data@app@com.example.test-2.apk@classes.dex
06-06 23:03:45.911: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.914: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.918: W/IconCustomizer(18569): can't load 
transform_config.xml
06-06 23:03:45.921: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.925: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.929: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.942: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.944: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.950: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.952: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.953: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.955: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.956: D/skia(18569): Flag is not 10
06-06 23:03:45.961: D/AndroidRuntime(18569): Shutting down VM
06-06 23:03:45.961: W/dalvikvm(18569): threadid=1: thread exiting     
with uncaught exception (group=0x419d59a8)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569): 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error 
inflating class org.osmdroid.views.MapView
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(
ActivityThread.java:2333)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at         
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(
ActivityThread.java:2385)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:157)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(
ActivityThread.java:1341)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:848)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:615)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569): Caused by: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error 
inflating class org.osmdroid.views.MapView
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
(LayoutInflater.java:768)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:816)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:559)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:419)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView
(PhoneWindow.java:354)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1981)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView
(MainActivity.java:63)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
(FragmentManager.java:885)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
(FragmentManager.java:1057)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:694)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
(FragmentManager.java:1435)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5233)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
(ActivityThread.java:2306)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    ... 11 more
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569): Caused by:     
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     
"org.osmdroid.views.MapView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file 
"/data/app/com.example.test-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=
[/data/app-lib/com.example.test-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass
(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:622)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    at     
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
(LayoutInflater.java:757)
06-06 23:03:45.964: E/AndroidRuntime(18569):    ... 25 more
06-06 23:03:48.547: I/Process(18569): Sending signal. 
PID: 18569 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Could you post your XML layout file?

Comment: Post the full logcat and your code

Comment: I solve it.
Add osmdroid-android-4.2.jar, osmdroid-third-party-4.2.jar, slf4j-android-1.7.7.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.7 as external JARs. And put all four files into the libs directory of the "test" project.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it. Add osmdroid-android-4.2.jar, osmdroid-third-party-4.2.jar, slf4j-android-1.7.7.jar and slf4j-api-1.7.7 as external JARs. And put all four files into the libs directory of the "test" project.